# Asymptotically tight bounds $P \left[1-\frac{1}{n} \le \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2 }{n} \le 1+\frac{1}{n} \right]$

Tags: probability, large-deviation-theory

I am looking for assymptotically tight bounds on
\begin{align}
P \left[1-\frac{1}{n} \le  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2 }{n} \le 1+\frac{1}{n} \right]=P \left[ \left| E[Z^2] - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2 }{n} \right| \le \frac{1}{n} \right]
\end{align} 
where $Z_i$ are i.i.d. standard normal.

I am sure these are available in the literature. I will Be grateful for a reference.

I am ultimately interested in

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} P \left[ \left| E[Z^2] - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2 }{n} \right| \le \frac{1}{n} \right]=???
\end{align}

Obviously, if we replace $\frac{1}{n}$ by some $\epsilon$ by a strong law of large number we would have that the limit is zero.  However, here things depended on the $n$.

Answer (score 1):

By central limit theorem $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2 }{n}$ is distributed as $N(1, \frac{2}n)$ for large $n$. Then your probability is:

$$P \approx \int_{1-\frac{1}n}^{1+\frac{1}n}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{4\pi}}e^{-\frac{n(x-1)^2}{4}}dx \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$